# Issues with autofilling checkboxes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Could I use a read only collection here and drop the `dataset`? I am new to `C#` and I am stumped at how to do this. I have a `dropdown-box` that is being filled from a column in `SQL` that holds client names. I have a `text-box` that you enter an email address into that will update the email address in `SQL` with the values checked in the `dropdown-box`. Now when the email is entered into the `textbox` is there a way I can pull these saved values from `SQL` and  have the `checkboxes` "auto" checked based on what is already in the table for the corresponding email? I have seen this done with coded values but not values from `SQL`. Also if an email has access to more than 1 client, the client names are pipe delimited when inserted into `SQL`.

Here Is what I have so far.

```
if (EmailList.Value == "") Connection ls = new Connection(); Recordset rs = new Recordset();
ls.Open(connections.myconn);

rs.Open("select email from users order by email", ls);

string emails = "";

while (!rs.EOF) { emails += rs.Fields[0].Value + " "; rs.MoveNext(); }

EmailList.Value = emails;

using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tracking_mpc order by ClientName"))
{
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.Connection = con1;
    con1.Open();
    webreport.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    webreport.DataTextField = "ClientName";
    webreport.DataValueField = "CltID";
    webreport.DataBind();
    con1.Close();
}
```

```
public string StringFromDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        string constr=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(constr))
        myConnect.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Clients from users WHERE Email =" + EmailTextBox.Text)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = command };
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        return dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Clients"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome  to stack !!Please see the section on how to ask a question....

Comment: An example solution might look like this: Save your email. Look up the email Row. Write setters for the checkboxes. Set the checkboxes based on the Properties returned from the email Row.

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer your question, but DON'T do this: `new SqlCommand("SELECT Clients from users WHERE Email =" + EmailTextBox.Text)`.  Please see: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Also, don't SELECT * from a table when you are only using a known number of fields.  Two in your case.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I understand this, I am just trying to get this thing working.

Comment: @RobertMcKee If you look at that `SELECT * ` Its binding to a drop down list so a select all is necessary.

Comment: Looks like you are databinding it to a control that only requires ClientName and CltID, in which case, you should be using `SELECT ClientName, CltID` instead of `SELECT *`.  Doing the SELECT * is inefficient in that it forces the SQL Server to look up the values for all the fields, possibly missing indexes, and/or causing additional IOs, and then increases network bandwidth to transfer all the columns when you only really wanted two.  Also as your DBA may want/need to add additional fields to support things like replication or audit logging, you will also retrieve those as well.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thank you for your insight

Comment: Note that in the first part of your code `if (EmailList.Value == "")` is only applied to `Connection ls = new Connection();` because the curly braces are missing. Also, please, indent the code correctly to make it more readable.

Comment: @Robert McKee `return cmd.ExecuteScalar().Split('|').ToList();` is giving error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no accessible extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to cast it to a string before calling split.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Cannot assign method group to an implicitly typed variable on line  var param = cmd.CreateParameter { ParameterName="@email", Value=email };

Comment: Fixed all the little errors I had in the database agnostic code.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Is it possible for me to add this to my on-click event? Right now I have protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e). Protected void is preventing me from returning a value.

Comment: return the value to what?

Comment: @RobertMcKee return ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).Split('|').ToList(); It gives me an error that my class returns a void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better implementation of your StringFromDatabase:

```
public List<string> GetClientNames(string email)
{
  var constr=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  var sql = "SELECT Clients FROM users WHERE Email=@email";

  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
    conn.Open();
    return ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).Split('|').ToList();
  }
}
```

Here is the same, but in a database agnostic way (works if you change your connection string to say MySql, Oracle, etc):

```
public List<string> GetClientNames(string email)
{
    var constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"];
    var sql = "SELECT Clients FROM users WHERE Email=@email";

    var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(constr.ProviderName);
    using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        conn.ConnectionString = constr.ConnectionString;
        var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@email";
        param.Value = email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        conn.Open();
        return ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).Split('|').ToList();
    }
}
```